# Subclipse installation fails "Subversion native library not available" (Java HL)

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse, eclipse-oxygen

I'm trying to setup a fresh installation of Eclipse Oxygen at work, and I'm running into this issue when trying to checkout any project.

Import -> Checkout Projects From SVN ->

[image: Error message]

I'm trying to migrate from an old Mars installation with the same plugins, so maybe it has something to do with two installations trying to share the same path (Or trying to search on their own path the configuration files). I was given the original installation "as is", so I don't really know how the configuration process went (And yeah, it works just fine).

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when the native Subversion JavaHL DLL's are being loaded, they try to load all of their dependencies.  This includes the OpenSSL DLL's (libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll).  These DLL's are included with JavaHL but it looks like you have some other version higher in the PATH.  More importantly these are 32-bit DLL's and you are running in a 64-bit JVM and loading 64-bit JavaHL.  So it cannot use them.

Maybe you can fix your PATH to get rid of these?  If not, you probably have to run 32-bit Eclipse using a 32-bit JVM.

You can also ignore the error and install the SVNKit adapter and choose to use that in your preferences under Team > SVN.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the (way too) late answer. I've ended up fixing the issue with SVN Kit. I don't really get the PATH problem, as I didn't had anything on the (system) path pointing to anything related with those libraries. Also, I installed the same Eclipse version at home and got the same problem. Maybe an issue with the old installation? A bug in the adapter itself?

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the errors on the screenshot. It seems that there is a problem with `java.library.path` or `%PATH%` environment variable.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I'm asking: "What's going on here?" I can see what the error message is telling, but I can't understand it. Configuration wise, both installations are similar, and have the same paths (Except the installation one, of course), so I don't get what is failing to find and how to fix it.